# Custom Class add to List, send to new Method first issues

Tags: c#

I have got a global class, which saves all instances of another class in memory, everytime a new instance is added though, it should also be sent to another method which displays it. This is the code below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Notifications held
/// Array((int)type,(string)"message")
/// </summary>
private List<Classes.notificationObject> _notifications;
public List<Classes.notificationObject> notifications
{
    get { return _notifications; }
    set
    {
        if (_notifications != value)
        {
            _notifications = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("notifications");

            //Show new notification
            Views.Notification x = new Views.Notification(value);
            x.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding I though that `value` would be just the `Classes.notificationObject` object, however i'm getting the following error:
Argument 1: cannot convert from

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'PhotoManagment.Classes.notificationObject'

This is the 'notificationObject':

```
public class notificationObject
{
private string _icon;
private string _message;
private string _detail;
private Color _color1;
private Color _color2;

public string Icon
{ get { return _icon; } set { _icon = value; }}
public string Message
{ get { return _message; } set { _message = value; }}
public string Detail
{ get { return _detail; } set { _detail = value; }}
public Color Color1
{ get { return _color1; } set { _color1 = value; }}
public Color Color2
{ get { return _color2; } set { _color2 = value; }}

public notificationObject newNotification(int type, string detail, string message)
{
    //Create new instance of object
    notificationObject x = new notificationObject();
    switch (type)
    {
        case 1:
            //Fatal
            x.Icon = "";
            x.Message = message;
            x.Detail = detail;
            x.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18);
            x.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16);
            return x;
        case 2:
            //Fatal
            x.Icon = "";
            x.Message = message;
            x.Detail = detail;
            x.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18);
            x.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16);
            return x;
        case 3:
            //Unauthorized
            x.Icon = "";
            x.Message = message;
            x.Detail = detail;
            x.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18);
            x.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16);
            return x;
        case 4:
            //Warning
            x.Icon = "";
            x.Message = message;
            x.Detail = detail;
            x.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0, 241, 176, 24);
            x.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 205, 152, 28);
            return x;
        case 5:
            //Warning
            x.Icon = "";
            x.Message = message;
            x.Detail = detail;
            x.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0, 41, 161, 213);
            x.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 36, 142, 184);
            return x;
        case 6:
            //Warning
            x.Icon = "";
            x.Message = message;
            x.Detail = detail;
            x.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0, 94, 129, 7);
            x.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 138, 183, 28);
            return x;
    }

    //Can't find error code
    x.Icon = "";
    x.Message = message;
    x.Detail = detail;
    x.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18);
    x.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16);
    return x;
}
```

**Edit 1**

Hmm, see if I was to use my 'runtimeObject' object now, and want to add a `notificationObject` to my list, I would by calling `runtimeObjectInstance.Add()'.

However `runtimeObject` will have many different properties, so isn't this a bad way to do it? Plus can't I do `runtimeObjectInstance.notifications.Add()` without coding it myself?

Comment: The value of that property is the list itself; List<Classes.notificationObject>. The value returned from a property will be the type of the property itself.

Comment: Your `newNotification` method looks like a factory method, but it's not static... which kinda defeats the purpose. You may want to post some of your code over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you're looking to improve your programming skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means your property expects a List of notificationObject(s). But you are assigning a "notificationObject" instead. Instead of doing it this way, you can derive your Collection class from IList and then use the "Add" method to populate it. If that's too hard, you can create a class with List property and implement "Add" method to populate the above collection type property.

Make sure to initialise your collection in your classes constructor.

```
public class MyList
{
    public MyList()
    {
        _notifications =  new List<notificationObject>();
    }

    private List<notificationObject> _notifications;
    public List<notificationObject> notifications
    {
        get { return _notifications; }
        set
        {
            if (_notifications != value)
            {
                _notifications = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("notifications");

                //I am not sure about this bit of code. You may have to test it again after doing this change.
                //Show new notification
                //Views.Notification x = new Views.Notification(value);
                //x.Show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(notificationObject newnotificationObject)
    {
        notifications.Add(newnotificationObject);
        OnPropertyChanged("notifications");
    }

    public void Remove(notificationObject existingnotificationObject)
    {
        if (notifications.Contains(existingnotificationObject))
        {
            notifications.Remove(existingnotificationObject);
            OnPropertyChanged("notifications");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample for the first method. If you are doing it this way, you will have implement all the methods.

```
 public class MyList2 : IList<notificationObject>
 {
    public int IndexOf(notificationObject item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, notificationObject item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public notificationObject this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Add(notificationObject item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(notificationObject item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(notificationObject[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool Remove(notificationObject item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<notificationObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I sort of understand what your saying, could you show a code example, nothing complex, so I can understand a bit more?

Comment: Answer updated. This is the 2nd method that I was talking about. On a side note; if you are not planning to assign a List to notifications, get rid of the setter. Also, you may have to move  //Views.Notification x = new Views.Notification(value);
                //x.Show(); to "Add()" method.

Comment: I understand now, I have done what you said before you edited your post and that works thanks! I moved the window creation to the `Add()` method. I will rename that to `AddNotification()` so it makes more sense.

Comment: You're welcome. Pls accept the answer if it was helpful. Thanks. :)

Comment: No need to create a custom collection class - `notifications` is already a `List`, so just call `notifications.Add(myNotification)` instead of `notifications = myNotification`. You may also want to use an `ObservableCollection<notificationObject>` so the UI gets notified about any added or removed items automatically.